# How to use the dojox.layout.ToggleSplitter widget in dijit.layout.BorderContainer?

Tags: dojo, border-container

like the title ,How to use the dojox.layout.ToggleSplitter widget  in dijit.layout.BorderContainer ? please say more, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I found this example:

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/layout/tests/test_ToggleSplitter.html

Look at the

```
<script type="dojo/method">
this._splitterClass = "dojox.layout.ToggleSplitter";
</script>
```

inside BorderContainer...
Regards,
Ote.